# How to say "My parents want me to be a doctor" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, causation

I want to say "My parents want me to be a doctor" in Japanese. My attempt is as follows but I am not quite sure whether it is correct or not.

> 両親は私を医者にならせたがっています。

Or

> 両親は私に医者になって欲しがっています。

Any comments and suggestions are really welcome.

Comment: I am just a fellow Japanese learner, but I might say either 「両親は私に医者になって欲しがっている。」(the latter) or 「両親は私が医者になることを望んでいる。」.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both 両親は私を医者にならせたがっています and 両親は私に医者になって欲しがっています are grammatically correct, but in practice, people don't say either. I'd recommend, as seafood258 says, 両親は私が医者になることを望んでいる or, if you ignore minor difference, …医者にならせたいようだ / …医者になってほしいようだ.